# Unable to make a HTTP request in Python

Tags: python, http, urllib2

I tried to use the following code to get the content on the `url`:

```
request  = urllib2.Request(url)
base64string = base64.encodestring('%s:%s' % (username, password)).replace('\n', '')
request.add_header("Authorization", "Basic %s" % base64string)
response = urllib2.urlopen(request,timeout=20)
```

I got the error:

```
urllib2.URLError: <urlopen error [Errno 10054] An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host>
```

But I am able to access the `url` using the same credential by a browser.

Comment: You'll need to obtain Telerik Fiddler and analyze the traffic to see what conditions need to be fulfilled to make your request palatable to the website.

Comment: Do you get this error if you don't first try to open the connection with the browser? Your browser connection may be the existing connection mentioned in the error message.

Comment: when you say "using the same credential by a browser" do you mean the browser was actually using HTTP Basic authentication, or you were entering that username/password into a web form?

Comment: @SamMason, using the username/password into a web form.

Comment: that's very different to using basic authentication, the web site would need to be programmed explicitly to support both (or happen to use a framework that does this automatically).  you'd probably need to use the developer tools built into your browser to see what happens during a login, e.g. where are credentials sent, any XSRF protections, etc, then replicate that in code.  note that this is against the terms and conditions of a lot of sites, and you should check with their admin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the issue.
Because through the web browser I am actually using a proxy but was not using it in Python script. 
Later I include the proxy before making the HTTP request and it works.